# Rest API Post in RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I was provided a snippet of code to make a call to a REST API and it works just fine, but i want to make the same call in RestSharp but cant quite figure it out the conversion.

Here is the code of the call that i want to convert to a restsharp call.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.apisite.co.uk/api/GetUser");

var postData = "api_key=123&api_secret=456&response_type=json&user_id=user1234";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "Post";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

responseString gives me my response in json.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var restClient = new RestClient("https://www.apisite.co.uk");
            var restRequest = new RestRequest("api/GetUser", Method.POST);
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter("api_key", "123");
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter("api_secret", "456");
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter("response_type", "json");
            restRequest.AddQueryParameter("user_id", "user1234");

            // response as a string
            var restResponseString = restClient.Execute(restRequest).Content;


            // response deserialized to an object/model
            var restResponseDeserialized = restClient.Execute<object>(restRequest).Data;
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, but when i do this i get an error response back from the api saying "Invalid API Credentials - No API Key has been provided." Also i plugged in the key and secret in what i have posted above, and it works just fine.